Regularity estimates of Double Layer potential
Let $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n,n\ge 2$ with $C^{\infty}$ boundary. Define $$I\left[ \phi \right](x) := -\frac{1}{\omega_n}\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{(x-y)\cdot \nu_y}{|x-y|^n}\phi(y)d\sigma(y)$$ as the double layer potential (DLP) of moment $\phi$, where $\omega_n = \frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$ is area of unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\nu_y$ is the outer normal to the domain $\Omega$ [Chp 3, Sec C]. I am given information that $g \in C^{k,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$ for some natural number $k\ge 1$, $0<\alpha<1$ and there exists a bounded $\phi$ such that $g(x) = I\left[\phi\right](x)$ for $x \in \Omega$. I am looking for references to find Schauder estimates for $\phi$ over the boundary. I reckon $\phi \in C^{k,\alpha}(\partial \Omega)$. Points over which I pondered:

Corollary 3.23 in Folland [Ref above] writes the moment $\phi$ in terms of the difference of the inner and outer function $u$ using theorem 3.22. However, in this case it is not useful since $g$ is really not defined outside $\overline{\Omega}$.
Using Theorem 3.22 in Folland, we have $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}\phi(x)+I\left[\phi\right](x)$ for $x\in \partial \Omega$. If the regularity of the DLP can be computed based on the behavior of the kernel then regularity of $\phi$ is known.
Pg 303 of this book states that if $\partial \Omega \in C^{m+1,\alpha}$ and $\phi \in C^{m,\alpha}(\partial \Omega)$, then $I[\phi]\in C^{m,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$ (extended continuously at the boundary by adding $\frac{1}{2}\phi$ at the boundary).

